# ASP.NET MVC Preserve Post Data After Authorize

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an action handling a form post, but I want to make sure they are authenticated before the action. The problem is that the post data is lost because they user is redirected to the login page, and then back.

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult AskQuestion(string question)
    {
       ....
    }
```

Any ideas?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to serialize your form values and a RedirectUrl to a hidden field.

After authentication deserialize the data in your hidden field and redirect based on the value of the RedirectUrl.

You will need a custom Authorize class to handle this.

Answer (score 4):

A POST is usually used for an add, update, or delete of data. By the time the user is doing this, if authentication is needed, you should have already authenticated them. So I would suggest that you change the flow of your app to authenticate before the POST.

Comment: Whilst I agree with the principle of what you're saying, I don't agree  that user data should be disposed of. It should be held, but not acted upon until the user can be authenticated. Otherwise, this makes for an unhelpful user experience when things like session timeouts happen.

Comment: I am not suggesting that data should be discarded. I am suggesting that before you begin to collect that data, the user be authenticated. E.g., rather than presenting the form, present a link to the the form, and if the user is not authenticated yet, take them to the login screen first. It is better practice to have them authenticate first, because the user will be annoyed if, after filling out a form, they are then required to sing-up/authenticate before they can submit. If they do not wish to register at that point, then the site has made them waste their time.

Comment: @D'ArcyRittich, how would you handle this issue if a signed in user takes a long time to fill out a form? In cases like that the user's authentication cookie might have expired and clicking submit would cause them to lose all of the filled out data. Besides periodically saving it or extending the cookie's timeout, do you know other ways? Thanks.

Comment: There are a few ways to handle this, but one way is to save the input in a cookie so you can repopulate the form with it the next time they go there if it has not already been submitted.

Answer (score -2):

You can also use the session to save the information...

Comment: If the user is logged out, typically because of a session timeout, he has, well, no session...